# Combining two arrays using ES6 spread operator in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to combine two arrays into one using the spread object like below:

```
const queryVariable = {
      ...this.state,
      filters: [...Object.keys(extraFilters || {}), ...this.state.filters],
    }
```

`this.state.filters` is an array here. But typescript gives me the following error:

`Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the typescript compilier options in tsconfig.json

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
 }
```

Refer this
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22768

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining (probably) about the ...this.state. Spread operator on objects is an ES2018 functionality.